# How to determine a VMs customization specification state with PowerShell (PowerCLI)?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

### Scenario

Im currently working on a Powershell script which should perform the following tasks:

1. Clone a given VM
2. Perform a Customization Specification task
3. Do some post clone tasks like domain join, move computer account in AD...

### Problem / Question

I need to detect the current state of the customization process. Is it possible to get it with a PowerCLI command?

**Note:** The following tasks fail, if I continue the script while the sysprep and reboot isn't finished within the customization task...

### Already tested scenarios

#### Wait-Tools

If already tried to wait for the completion of the syspep with the power-cli command wait-tools. The problem here is, that the vmware tools are already working before the sysprep is finished and scripts runt into errors because the vm still needs its final reboot after the sysprep

#### VI-Events

I even tried to work with the recent VI events of the targe machines. Especially reacting on the events "CustomizationStartedEvent", "CustomizationSucceeded" and "CustomizationFailed"
Same situaton loke with the wait-tools: the "CustomizationSucceeded" events will be emitted when the sysprep is finished and the vm waits for the final reboot

#### Replacing Restart-VMGuest with Restart-Computer

Both of the commands raises the error 'VMTools not running' or 'WinRM not running'.

#### Testing VMware tools state with VM properties

I also tried to get the vmware tools state with `$GetVMNew.ExtensionData.Guest.ToolsRunningStatus`. But its the same result like Wait-Tools

#### Reacting on `guestcust.log` content

The last entry in the log has the same timestamp like the 'CustomizationSucceeded' VI event. So this would cause the same timing problem for the reboot

#### Waiting for the Domain Join

The domain join happens just before the sysprep is finished and the vm self isn't up yet

Comment: You could use `Wait-Tools`, a PowerCLI command that waits for VMWare Tools to be available on the guest VM. This would indicate the reboot is finished.

Comment: I probably should have said something like "what code have you tried so far?" before posting an answer, but oh well there you go

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean the state of the CustomizationSpec, anyway you can use the `Get-OSCustomizationSpec` PowerCLI cmdlet to work with Customization Specs:

For example you can Change the Network Address, Set VM Name etc. See Example to Change the IP Address of the spec prior to the clone process:

```
Get-OSCustomizationSpec ConfSpecName | 
Get-OSCustomizationNicMapping | 
Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping -IpMode:"UseStaticIP" -IpAddress 10.0.0.10 `
-SubnetMask "255.255.255.0" -DefaultGateway 10.0.0.254 -Dns 10.0.0.100
```

See all PowerCLI CustomizationSpec Cmdlets:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command *OS*Spec* | Select Name

Name
----
Get-OSCustomizationSpec
New-OSCustomizationSpec
Remove-OSCustomizationSpec
Set-OSCustomizationSpec
```

Comment: I have to wait with the following steps in my script until the customization Specification is done with the new cloned vm. If I just try to get it with Wait-Tools the script continues while the new vm is still in the sysprep or reboot cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest approach would be to use `Get-VIEvent` to look for the "Customization Succeeded" event. Or if your OS customization process includes a new guest hostname, wait for the `$_.Guest.Hostname` property from `Get-VM` to pick up the new name.

In one scenario, I'm handling a similar problem by including a shutdown command as part of the `-GuiRunOnce` argument to `New-OsCustomizationSpec`. Then after starting the vm following the clone process, I wait for the vm to finish powering up (`Wait-Tools` might be just as good here - I honestly don't recall why I'm not using it.)

```
"Waiting for vmtools to get IP address..."
do {
  Start-Sleep -Sec 3
  $cloneObj = Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine -Property Guest -Filter @{"name" = $vmname}
  $IP = $cloneObj.Guest.IPaddress
} until ($IP)
```

Then I wait until the `-GuiRunOnce` shutdown command has completed and the vm is off, at which point it's safe to assume that sysprep and customization are finished (unless the OS has crashed, I suppose).

```
"Preparing clone. Sysprep will take a few minutes..."
do {Start-Sleep -Sec 3}
until ((Get-VM $vmName | Select -Expand PowerState) -eq "PoweredOff")
```

Of course you'll probably want to re-start the vm afterwards. And this might be a bit Rube Goldberg-ish for your needs; I need the vm off temporarily for other reasons, but the basic suggestion is to use `-GuiRunOnce` as a way to confirm that the OS is up following sysprep customization. Instead of shutting down, you could write a file somewhere and then check for its presence, or etc. `Invoke-VMScript` might also be helpful, if for example your clone won't be able to reach your network right away, and the completion of your `-GuiRunOnce` action would only be verifiable from inside the clone.

You might consider joining the domain within the OS customization process, rather than afterwards. With the AD computer account specifically, I suppose you could check whether or not it exists where you expect before attempting to move it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this API: https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/vim.event.CustomizationEvent.html
Just wait for the event and continue once one of it appears.